# Best way to deal with IDs only containing numbers

Tags: wit.ai

We're trying to display some booking information to the users and we're asking to them the ID which has a 10 length numbers format like this one: **1553296942**

In the stories, we try to identify the user input with an intent called *bookingStatus* and a entity called *uid*.

[image: Story]

Thing is, this IDs are recognized as a **wit/location** type (it looks like coordinates to him, I guess) and it doesn't recognize them properly most of the times.

What would be the best approach to handle this situation?

For now, in the Understanding tab we're feeding the bot with lots of these IDs, adding the intent *bookingStatus* and marking it as *uid* entity aswell. Is this the right thing and shall we continue training it this way?

[image: Understanding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed with the 10-length numbers. Actually there are only 10^10 possibilities for the **uid** entity. You can basically feed the whole 10^10 possibilities with a simple CURL command which contains a loop to 10^10.

How do you feed your NLP without the Understanding tab? Well..

Check the HTTP API Docs here
https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#post--entities-:entity-id-values-link

Have a nice day!